# How does the speed of CUDA program scale with the number of blocks?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I am working on Tesla C1060, which contains 240 processor cores with compute capability 1.3. Knowing that each 8 cores are controlled by a single multi-processor, and that each block of threads is assigned to a single multi-processor, then I would expect that launching a grid of 30 blocks, should take the same execution time as one single block. However, things don't scale that nicely, and I never got this nice scaling even with 8 threads per block. Going to the other extreme with 512 threads per block, I get approximately the same time of one block, when the grid contains a maximum of 5 blocks. This was disappointing when I compared the performance with implementing the same task parallelized with MPI on an 8-core CPU machine.
Can some one explain that to me?

By the way, the computer actually contains two of this Tesla card, so does it distribute blocks between them automatically, or do I have to take further steps to ensure that both are fully exploited?

EDIT:
Regarding my last question, if I launch two independent MPI processes on the same computer, how can I make each work on a different graphics card?

EDIT2: Based on the request of Pedro, here is a plot depicting the total time on the vertical access, normalized to 1 , versus the number of parallel blocks. The number of threads/block = 512. The numbers are rough, since I observed quite large variance of the times for large numbers of blocks.
[image]

Comment: How far off is the observed scaling from the expected scaling? Can you add a scaling or efficiency plot over the number of blocks?

Comment: Thirty blocks is still far too few to fully occupy your card. You need something like 3-8 blocks *per* MP to get all the scheduling latency and architecture overheads amortized. You should be looking at block counts between 90 and 240 to hit peak throughput on a C1060.

Comment: @talonmies The time taken to execute 240 blocks equals approximately 9 times the time taken for 30 blocks. This means that maximum throughput was already reached at 30 blocks or even less.

Comment: Either you are running very small blocks or not timing correctly. The gt200 is an architecture I did a lot of work with and from what I learned about it porting the linpack benchmark and writing a lot of linear algebra code, your results make no sense.whatsoever

Comment: I am timing correctly, and the size of the block is already stated above. I found now, that what makes my code doesn't scale nicely is the global memory access. Without it, indeed the time for 30 blocks is almost the same as one block. This is probably what you missed to learn.

Comment: Can you attach the code?

Answer (score 1):

The speed is not a simple linear relation with the number of blocks. It depends on bunch of stuffs. For example, the memory usage, the number of instruction excuted in a block, etc.

If you want to do multi-GPU computing, you need to modify your code, otherwise you can only use one GPU card.

Comment: Comparing with my CPU performance using MPI and the same task, the GPU is not much better, not even with an order of magnitude! What kind of modifications are required for using the other GPU card?

Comment: "one block can be assigned with multiple multiprocessor" --- isn't it the other way around? Each block resides completely within one MP, but one MP can handle several blocks.

Comment: @chaohuang then I think the whole statement should be removed from the answer as it doesn't explain the slowness of performing many blocks in parallel compared to one block.

Comment: The number of CUDA cores is not relevant. Tesla C1060 has 30 multiprocessors. Your performance will scale based upon multiprocessor utilization and bus utilization. For example if you have a lot of memory accesses you will need at least 6 warps to keep the multiprocessor busy. You want all blocks to be multiples of WARP_SIZE threads. You must manually launch work on multiple GPUs. CUDA provides no mechanism to transparently launch work across multiple devices.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you have simply taken a C program and compiled it in CUDA without much tought.

Dear friend, this is not the way to go. You have to design your code to take advantage of the fact that CUDA cards have a different internal architecture than regular CPUs. In particular, take the following into account:

- **memory access pattern** -  there is a number of memory systems in a GPU and each requires consideration on how to use it best
- **thread divergence problems** - performance will only be good if most of your threads follow the same code path most of the time

If your system has 2 GPUs, you can use both to accelerate some(suitable) problems. The thing is that the memory area of the two are split and not easily 'visible' by each other - you have to design your algorithm to take this into account.

A typical C program written in pre-GPU era will often not be easily transplantable unless originally written with MPI in mind.

To make each CPU MPI thread work with a different GPU card you can use cudaSetDevice()